# remove time from date in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a query

```
select count(1) z1
        from sales_data
        where ed_date >= sysdate -7
```

i need to group by ed
_date, remove the timestamp, and condition where ed_date is from 1/1/2021 to current sysdate

Answer (score 1):

You can [truncate the date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79):

```
select trunc(ed_date, 'DD') as ed_date, count(*) as z1
from sales_data
where ed_date >= date '2021-01-01'
and ed_date < trunc(sysdate, 'DD')
group by trunc(ed_date, 'DD')
```

The `'DD'` truncation limit is the default so you could omit that, as just `trunc(ed_date)`, if you prefer. Note though that it doesn't *remove* the time, it just sets it to midnight - an Oracle date always has both date and time components.

You can also `order by trunc(ed_date)`, and in the select list you can format that however you want:

```
select to_char(trunc(ed_date), MM/DD/YYYY') as ed_date, count(*) as z1
from sales_data
where ed_date >= date '2021-01-01'
and ed_date < trunc(sysdate)        -- to exclude today and future
-- and ed_date < trunc(sysdate) + 1 -- to include today but not tomorrow onwards
group by trunc(ed_date)
order by trunc(ed_date)
```

Comment: And if you want to include today, make this `and ed_date < trunc(sysdate, 'DD') + 1` or `and ed_date < trunc(sysdate, 'DD') + interval '1' day`.

Comment: Or leave the `and ...` off if you want today, up to the current time, and there are no values in the future *8-)

Comment: still getting the ed_date as 1/1/2021 12:00:00  AM

Comment: its still showing the timestamp in ed_date

Comment: my date is in format mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @donaldsmith - like I said, it sets the time to midnight, but it's still there. If you want to display the date in a specific format then convert it to a string explicitly. I've added a version that does that.